# Tabular mode disabled during SSAS installation

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am trying to install SSAS in Tabular Mode. However, i find that the radio button is disabled. I am installing it on a separate instance as well. The regular Multidimensional SSAS  had been installed first.I am installing Standard SQL server .[image] .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That option is only available for Enterprise and Business Intelligence editions:

[Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

And, of course, for Developer Edition.