# StorageEngineUsed set to TabularMetadata. For databases in this mode, you must use Tabular APIs to administer the database

Tags: restore, ssas, automation, tabular-model, ssas-2016

I am an [administrator in SSAS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/206771/22336).

I have many data warehouse servers.

In some servers I have SQL Server and SSAS [on the same machine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/108358/22336).

I [successfully backup the SSAS databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/81928/22336) and even [check if the backups are healthy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84048/22336)

Recently, however, one of our servers which is managed by a third party company based in Canada, needed to be replaced, and while migrating all the ssas databases from the old server to the new one

this is the old server:
[image]

this is the new server:
[image]

I am getting this error message while `processing` the database in the new server:

> This command cannot be executed on database 'DWCA' because it has been
>   defined with StorageEngineUsed set to TabularMetadata. For databases
>   in this mode, you must use Tabular APIs to administer the database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I manage to find a [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27830/22336) for this.
Unfortunately, there are no ways (at least that I could find) to change SSAS, that worked in all environments.

I did this:
[How to uninstall SSAS](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-uninstall-ssas)

[Changing an Analysis Services instance to tabular mode](https://cathydumas.com/2012/04/23/changing-an-analysis-services-instance-to-tabular-mode/)

It worked in some servers but not on other server.
Also:

[Be Careful ! SSAS Analysis services cannot be uninstalled from a SQL cluster once installed](https://rahmanagoro.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/be-careful-ssas-analysis-services-cannot-be-uninstalled-from-a-sql-cluster-once-installed/)

Therefore my solution was to change SSAS when [not possible to remove SSAS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/245331/22336).
what I was really wanted to achieve was to get the tabular mode installed with default instance name.

get to this:
[image]

More information is here:

[Install SQL Server Analysis Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions)

and specially this link:

[Determine the Server Mode of an Analysis Services Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/determine-the-server-mode-of-an-analysis-services-instance?view=asallproducts-allversions)

After that you can check [Tabular In-Memory mode](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/142506/22336), which is very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to process your tabular model (which is of version >= 1200) with XMLA script (so all in all command is in XML). That kind of tabular model has to be processed with JSON command. I had the same error message and it just turned out that I was trying to refresh the newer tabular model (of version >=1200) with XMLA command. After using JSON command - it all worked. Probably for some reason while moving the tabular model from one server to another - the version of that tabular model was somehow upgraded to >= 1200. Or you are using old SSMS which is only capable of producing XMLA commands.